# useEffect inside a reused custom hook executes multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a custom hook that is used by N components across the app at the same time.

Inside the custom hook there is a useEffect which executes at the right time / correctly given the dependencies however it executes N number of times (with each component where it is loaded)... which seems right.

I was wondering nevertheless if there would be a way to make it execute only once even though it's "parent" custom hook is "mounted" multiple times.

Thanks

Comment: What does your effect do and why do you want it to be executed only once? You may want to use a context instead of/alongside your custom hook

Comment: Can you provide some code so we can try and help you out with your own scenario

Answer (score 0):

```
let alreadyCalled = false;
function myHook() {  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (alreadyCalled) {
      return;
    }
    alreadyCalled = true;
    //calculate here
  })
}
```

Comment: Its probably best to save this as a state not as a variable

Comment: Sure, but this is just example for understanding

Answer (score 0):

The point of `useEffect` is to bind the execution of a piece of logic to the lifecycle of the component(s) where it is used. You're asking how to not tie that logic to the lifecycle of certain components.

It sounds like it should not be used in any of those N components, but perhaps in a parent component which would then pass the resulting state down via props or context.

If it's buried in a custom hook, you might need to pull it out of there, call it in parent component, and pass whatever state it produces as an argument to that custom hook.